# Windows 8.1 new apps on start menu

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, icons, start-menu

I want to get icons of the new installed apps directly on my start screen. I don't like to pin every app to my start screen before it's easy to access it.
Does someone know how I can do that in Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is not possible anymore, it's part of the changes introduced in windows 8.1

Here is an article that mention it : http://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-customize-the-new-start-screen-in-windows-8-1/

Comment: The new Apps will be highlighted in Update 1 to make them easier to find. http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-81-update-1-review